# "Available from" plus date meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am considering applying for a job, which is a one-year post. Contract duration in the Job announcement reads "available from September 2019 for 12 months". Does it mean that the candidate is expected to start exactly in September or at some point since September?

Comment: Depends on the context. You don't say *what* is available from September. If (as seems likely) it says something like "the candidate must be available from September" then I would take that to mean they want you to start work in September. If, on the other hand, it says, "The contract is available from September" then it might mean that you could start anytime after that (within the next 12 months).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for the insufficient info I have given. In its entirety it reads: "Contract Duration: Available from September 2019 for 12 Months "

Answer (score 1):

You should assume the vacancy begins at the beginning of September 2019. It is possible, 
but unlikely, that they mean the vacancy has another specific start date within September. If the latter were the case, they would have normally stated it.

Speaking as an employer, I am in most cases willing to wait a little time for the right candidate. Therefore, if the best candidate says, for example, "I am only available from 19 October," as an employer I will in most cases agree to wait until then. It will depend on how strong the candidate is in comparison to the others.

In practice the best approach is to go to the interview, and see how it goes. If you are successful, gently open up discussion afterwards regarding potential starting dates. You might be surprised how flexible they are.